# style table rows based on value (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was not able to style table rows based on row values.

Currently I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".bulkGridClass").find("td").each(function () {               
               $(this).css("color", "Red");               
            });
        });
```

But instead I need something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".bulkGridClass").find("td").each(function () {               
           // IF TD CONTAINS TEXT "File" THEN add color red
           $(this).css("color", "Red");               
        });
    });
```

I have tried to use something like this:

```
    $(this).contains("File")
```

but this shows me `$(this)` doesn't have `contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text()` function will return the text of the node. You can combine that with `indexOf()` to check for the string you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bulkGridClass").find("td").each(function () {               
       if ($(this).text().indexOf('File') > -1)
           $(this).css("color", "Red");               
    });
});
```

Another (probably better) option would be to use the `:contains()` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bulkGridClass td:contains("File")').css("color", "Red");               
});
```

Note that `:contains()` is case-sensitive, so `File != file`.

Answer (score 1):

Can skip the `$.each` and just do:

```
$(".bulkGridClass td:contains('File')").css("color", "Red");
```

If case sensitive:

```
$(".bulkGridClass td").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('file') >-1;
}).css("color", "Red");
```

Provide some sample markup for test case